# P4::run_edit giving error when run for a loong time in a ruby script

Tags: ruby, perforce

I made one ruby script in which I first initialized one object of `P4` which is `$p4` by initializing `$p4.user`, `$p4.password` and executed `$p4.connect` and `$p4.run_login`.

Then I used `P4::run_edit` to open the file for editing in the same script. For the first 3-4 hours of the execution of the ruby script the command successfully opened many files for editing , allowed the ruby script to do the modification in the file but after that the script was not able to open one file for editing and it gave the below error.

```
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/P4.rb:129:in `run': [P4#run] Errors during command execution( "p4 edit Filename" ) (P4Exception)
```

Can somebody tell me what can be the reason behind this and how to fix it . I thought that the problem occured because the script ran for many hours and it was not possible for perforce to make the connection established for such a long time. But I am not sure about it.

```
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/P4.rb:129:in `run': [P4#run] Errors during command execution( "p4 edit Filename" ) (P4Exception)
```

Comment: its probably because the file is already open. Did you try closing and reopening it for edit?. If it worked once, it should work again

Comment: No the was not already opened. Lemme explain:
1. I opened the file for editing using p4_object.run_edit
2. Then I opened it using File.open 
3. Started operating on the files
The above operations successfully executed for more than 300 files but it created problem in between the execution.

Comment: What is the actual output from the 'p4 edit Filename' command? That is, what error is occurring during the failed 'p4 edit Filename' execution?

Comment: when I tried opening the file using p4 edit command on the terminal it worked absolutely fine. There was no error.